# How to capture a Javascript function's return value into a PHP variable?

Tags: php, javascript

How to capture a Javascript function's return value into a PHP variable?

Example:

Javascript: `javascriptFunction { return null;};`

PHP: `$php_variable = javascriptFunction();`

If clarification is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Yes... what is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript runs on the client side, while PHP runs on the server side. As such, you cannot execute JavaScript code inside your PHP code; however, these two components can communicate via several channels including:

1. [HTTP Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)
2. [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)
3. [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

The easiest approach would be to set a query parameter on your URL: `example.com/?variable=value` and access it from your PHP script using, `$_GET['variable']`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Without any idea of what you're trying to do...

Use jquery (with ajax):

```
$.get("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Where test is the php file you're sending data to, and John and 2pm are the data.

Then in test.php do:

```
$name = $_GET['name']
```

and do the same for time!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to AJAX the value to the server and pull it from `$_GET` or `$_POST`:

```
$.ajax({type:"get", data:javascriptFunction(), url:script.php });
```

Then, simply use `$value = $_GET`.